# ¿Cómo puedo escribir los datos que recibo via formulario en un archivo xml?

Tags: php, wordpress, xml, data

¿Cómo podría escribir los datos que recibo via POST - formulario en un archivo xml?

¿PHP? ¿Javascript? ¿Cuál es el camino más optimo?

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas especialmente [ask] y [mcve]. Te recomiendo que reformules tu pregunta editandola, así como está es probable que termine siendo cerrada por ser demasiado amplia. Saludos

Comment: Básicamente lo puedes hacer con cualquier lenguaje que te permita generar un archivo. Pues un xlm no es más que un archivo de texto.